# Button disappears after click when using UseSubmitBehavior as false

Tags: asp.net

Below is the code.

Everything else is working fine. Just when the user clicks btnWhishlist (if user not logged-in) ModalPopupExtender displays for login. On popup whether Cancel or Login is clicked, even if the user gets logged in, the btnWishlist button disappears.

When the page is reloaded the button appears again. Looks like UseSubmitBehavior="false" is creating the problem. The page do not reload but only the button disappears, everything else remains same.

```
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="usrListShowImages" runat="server" OnItemCommand="usrListShowImages_ItemCommand"   OnItemCreated="usrListShowImages_ItemCreated" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
    some layout
    </LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" ID="up_inlv"> 
        <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="divWishlist" class="wishlist" runat="server">
            <div class="<%--growuser--%>picUserShow">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImages" ImageUrl='<%# ".." + Eval("ItemsPicUrl") %>' runat="server" CssClass="growuser" CommandName="btnImages" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

                <asp:Panel class="bottomDiv" runat="server" id="btmDiv"> <%-- HAVE USER SIGNIN, CHECK FROM DB THAT THIS ITEM WAS ADDED TO WISHLIST OR NOT AND THEN ALOT THE BUTTON TEXT ACCORDINGLY --%>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnWhishlist" Text='<%# Eval("colbtnwishlist") %>' runat="server" CssClass="wishlistButton" CommandName="btnWhishlist" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="true" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:Panel>
                <div class="bottomDivCart">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCart" Text="Cart" runat="server" CssClass="CartButton" CommandName="btnCart" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' EnableViewState="true" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <%# Eval("captionforpage") %>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.<%# Eval("priceofarticle") %></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </ContentTemplate>                    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>                
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>




HTML PART
---------

<div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_0">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_0" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl0$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_0" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//1431892337134536.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_0" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_0">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl0$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl0$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_0" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_0">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl0$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl0$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_0" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                                    item1
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.5</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_1">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_1" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl1$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_1" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//1431892647134505.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_1" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_1">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl1$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl1$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_1" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_1">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl1$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl1$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_1" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.6</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_2">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_2" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl2$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_2" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//1424700827853687.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_2" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_2">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl2$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl2$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_2" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_2">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl2$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl2$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_2" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.11</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_3">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_3" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl3$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_3" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//1424711471185956.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_3" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_3">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl3$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl3$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_3" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_3">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl3$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl3$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_3" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.12</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_4">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_4" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl4$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_4" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//12009542_381168112090913_9072379345912822386_n.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_4" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_4">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl4$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl4$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_4" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_4">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl4$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl4$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_4" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                                    12009542_381168112090913_9072379345912822386_n.jpg
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.20</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_5">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_5" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl5$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_5" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//12170570_172803673063585_1648079375_n.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_5" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_5">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl5$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl5$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_5" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_5">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl5$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl5$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_5" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                                    12170570_172803673063585_1648079375_n.jpg
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.21</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>




    </div>                
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_up_inlv_6">



                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_divWishlist_6" class="wishlist">
                            <div class="picUserShow">
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl6$btnImages" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnImages_6" class="growuser" src="..//Content//Uploads//12170570_172803673063585_1648079375_n.jpg" />




                    <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btmDiv_6" class="bottomDiv">

                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl01_6">

                        <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl6$btnWhishlist" value="Not Wished" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl6$btnWhishlist&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnWhishlist_6" class="wishlistButton" /> 

            </div>

        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivCart">
                        <div id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_ctl03_6">

                                <input type="button" name="ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl6$btnCart" value="Cart" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$FirstContent$UserImageShowControl1$usrListShowImages$ctrl6$btnCart&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="FirstContent_UserImageShowControl1_usrListShowImages_btnCart_6" class="CartButton" />

        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                                    12170570_172803673063585_1648079375_n.jpg
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.1</div>
                        </div>
                            </div>  </div>                
        </tr>
        </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure somebody has faced such a problem

Comment: And what's the actual code, i.e., the one that was produced by the template and served to the web client?

Comment: Hi, @matcheek Thanks for replying. The source gets the button name as MasterPage_UserControlname_ListviewName_btnwhishlist_ctrl00

then
MasterPage_UserControlname_ListviewName_btnwhishlist_ctrl00_2 and so on

Comment: I can provide you teamviewer id to have a look

Comment: You don't need to give TeamViewer to people...just paste your HTML here

Comment: HTML = source view of browser?

Comment: yes the View Source window of your browser shows the entire HTML document which was prepared by the server and downloaded into your browser. Essentially this is the final output from running the ASP.NET code.

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I have added the HTML generated