# ASP.NET Button inside listview vanishes after click when using submit behavior set as false

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, button, postback

Below is the code.

Everything else is working fine. Just when the user clicks btnWhishlist (if user not logged-in) ModalPopupExtender displays for login. On popup whether Cancel or Login is clicked, even if the user gets logged in, the btnWishlist button disappears.

When the page is reloaded the button appears again. Looks like UseSubmitBehavior="false" is creating the problem. The page do not reload but only the button disappears, everything else remains same.

Tried jquery to show the panel/div that contains the button. No Luck.

```
<ContentTemplate >
     <asp:ListView ID="usrListShowImages" runat="server" OnItemCommand="usrListShowImages_ItemCommand"   OnItemCreated="usrListShowImages_ItemCreated" >
 <LayoutTemplate>
 some layout
 </LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" ID="up_inlv"> 
     <ContentTemplate>

     <div id="divWishlist" class="wishlist" runat="server">
         <div class="<%--growuser--%>picUserShow">
             <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImages" ImageUrl='<%# ".." + Eval("ItemsPicUrl") %>' runat="server" CssClass="growuser" CommandName="btnImages" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

             <asp:Panel class="bottomDiv" runat="server" id="btmDiv"> <%-- HAVE USER SIGNIN, CHECK FROM DB THAT THIS ITEM WAS ADDED TO WISHLIST OR NOT AND THEN ALOT THE BUTTON TEXT ACCORDINGLY --%>
                 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
                         <asp:Button ID="btnWhishlist" Text='<%# Eval("colbtnwishlist") %>' runat="server" CssClass="wishlistButton" CommandName="btnWhishlist" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="true" />
                     </ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </asp:Panel>
             <div class="bottomDivCart">
                 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
                         <asp:Button ID="btnCart" Text="Cart" runat="server" CssClass="CartButton" CommandName="btnCart" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' EnableViewState="true" />
                     </ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
             </div>
             <div class="caption">
                 <%# Eval("captionforpage") %>
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="priceTag">Price Rs.<%# Eval("priceofarticle") %></div>
         </div>
     </div>

     </ContentTemplate>                    
 </asp:UpdatePanel>                
     </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>

There are no errors so far. The wish button should show up without having a page reload, the same way the other artifacts are showing up
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Button disappears after click when using UseSubmitBehavior as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850251/asp-net-button-disappears-after-click-when-using-usesubmitbehavior-as-false)

Comment: Yes, It was posted in wrong area. I would appreciate if you guys can help here . .